# GNU Radio and USRP audio source problem

Tags: digital-communications, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, usrp

I have a modem which accepts a voice in GNU Radio, digitizes and compresses it (codec2) and transmits it using USRP on one laptop and receives it on another laptop.
When I use "Wave File Source" in the transmitter everything is OK and I clearly hears the voice from "Audio Sink" at the receiver, but as I switch to "Audio Source" at the transmitter, nothing can be heared!
On one laptop, there is no problem but with sample rate of 1.6 MHz, there is about 3 seconds of delay in voice.

I wonder why and would be pleased if someone introduces some tricks in working with "Audio Source/Sink" in GNU Radio.

Comment: do you happen to get anything like *U* printed on your console? Both your USRP and your sound card have a physical sampling rate, and the processing between these two must, in effect, convert the input rate to the output rate. Note that neither sound cards nor USRPs can run at *arbitrary* sampling rates!

Comment: It shows some "U" at the Tx but stops after a while (not continuously printed)

Comment: hm, that doesn't sound good. Does it by any chance tell you it's stopped doing, or emit another single letter like "S" or "D" before stopping? Is some == 2 or is some more like 200?

Comment: let's ask this explicitly: does your signal processing make sure that the 44.1 kHz, or 48 kHz, or whatever your audio source produces is converted to the sampling rate of your USRP sink?

Comment: Maybe add your GNU Radio flow graph to your question? If you're using GNU Radio companion (GRC), there's "File-> Screen Capture", which will be very useful.

Comment: Thanks Marcus!
There is no "S" or "D" at the Tx and I use B200mini.
The exact count of "U"s is 5 (after 10 seconds of running)
I set sample rate of audio source to 8000 Hz and after codec2 (2400 bps) and preamble adding of 128 bits to 384 audio samples (2400 becomes 3200 bps), it gots interpolated by 512 to yield 1638400 Hz, which is the sample rate of USRP.

Comment: most soundcards can't do 8 kHz as a sampling rate.

Comment: Yes, but I tested 48 kHz and decimated it to 8 kHz but nothing!
Can I resample audio source to a bit higher sample rate to get rid of "U"s at Tx?

Comment: in theory, yes, but the reality is that the clocks of the USRP and the soundcards will be drifting... but this seems to be a different problem! (you're not getting *many* Us, so let's solve that later)

Comment: hm, can you verify that audio source -> codec2 encoder > codec2 decoder -> audio sink works on the same computer?

Comment: I've tested that and it's ok.